# Most frequently used strings in a file 

Tags: perl, file, sorting

I found a post here were someone managed to read information from a file and sort out the most commonly used words and return how many times each word was used. The input was from a command line argument but I want to get the same script to be executed and then take the filename to be run through the script as input. I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

```
print "Type the name of the file: ";
chomp(my $file = <>);

open (FILE, "$file") or die;

while (<FILE>){
    $seen{$_}++ for split /\W+/;
}

my $count = 0;
for (sort {
    $seen{$b} <=> $seen{$a}
              ||
       lc($a) cmp lc($b)
              ||
          $a  cmp  $b
} keys %seen)
{
    next unless /\w/;
    printf "%-20s %5d\n", $seen{$_}, $_;
    last if ++$count > 100;
}
close (FILE);
```

My result at the moment is:

```
15                       0
15                       0
10                       0
10                       0
10                       0
5                        1
5                        0
5                        0
5                        0
5                        0
```

The result I want is:

```
<word>             <number of occurances>
<word>             <number of occurances>
<word>             <number of occurances>
<word>             <number of occurances>
<word>             <number of occurances>
<word>             <number of occurances>
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you told us HOW this is not working.

Comment: This program hasn't produced the output you show: there is no way the counts in `%seen` can be zero. But apart from being poor-quality Perl your program works fine. Try it with a different input file

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
printf "%-20s %5d\n", $seen{$_}, $_;
```

is the reverse of what you intended. `$_` is a string, and `$seen{$_}` is the count of how many times `$_` appears in the text (a number), so you want to say either

```
printf "%-20s %5d\n", $_, $seen{$_};
```

or

```
printf "%5d %-20s\n", $seen{$_}, $_;
```

Comment: @John: If it has solved your problem then please consider to mark the answer as "Accepted".

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You are reading the user entered file input into the variable `$seen` instead of `$file`.
2. You need to chomp your the input that you receive to get rid of the trailing newlin:

   ```
   my $file= <>;
   chomp($file);
   ```

   or the short form:

   ```
   chomp(my $file = <>);
   ```

Comment: Thanks, added the chomp but it didn't change the output

Answer (score 0):

In the second line you want to put the name of the file to open into $file, not $seen. So:

```
chomp(my $file = <>);
```

The chomp gets rid of the newline at the end (from pressing enter).

Comment: Ah, thanks, Ive changed the script so many times I don't know whats what anymore.